# MSDOS "Hello World" EXE

Tags: dos

I want to compile a "Hello World" MS-DOS exe.

Not a program that runs in XP 16bit mode, or in MS-DOS mode on top of Windows OSs.

A HELOWRLD.EXE that I can run on my MS-DOS box.

Comment: In what (programming) language?

Comment: echo Hello World

(that will write what u need), perhaps you need something more specific, tell us

Comment: Here are examples in many languages (OS listed next to them). As others have pointed out - most likely you are going to use C, C++, Assembly, or even dos batch.
http://www.ntecs.de/old-hp/uu9r/lang/html/lang.en.html

Comment: An MS-DOS exe does run in 16 bit mode, unless one of the various 32 bit extenders are used.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think `DEBUG.EXE` still ships with windows (at least it does with XP). Run debug and enter something along the lines of the following transcript:

```
c:\src> debug
-a 100
1373:0100 mov ah,9
1373:0102 mov dx,108
1373:0105 int 21
1373:0107 ret
1373:0108 db "Hello world!$"
1373:0115
-n c:\hi.com
-r bx
BX 0000
:0
-r cx
CX 0000
:15
-w
Writing 00015 bytes
-q

c:\src> c:\hi.com
Hello world!

c:\src> _
```

Read more on DEBUG.EXE at: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debug_(command)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debug_%28command%29)

And the INT 21 display string http at: http://www.uv.tietgen.dk/staff/mlha/PC/Prog/asm/int/21/09.htm

Comment: All the answers have been really helpful - but as you opened a door for me :) awarded Thanks!!

Comment: It isn't there in Windows 7 x64, probably because it's a 16-bit app.

Comment: 21 byte executable!! Love it!!

Comment: Regarding the $ symbol: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20411716/2188550

Answer (score 9):

Follow these steps:

1. Get and install Turbo C 2.0 from [here, legally](http://edn.embarcadero.com/museum).
2. Copy this code (*)
3. Compile it.
4. Your hello.exe is ready to run.

This is code you should copy (*):

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   printf("Hello, world.\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's also DJGPP, which is real free software and not just abandonware: http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/

Comment: Totally agree with both of you. I just happen to love old Borland compilers. They were AWESOME!

Comment: Can I suggest you get the Borland compilers from the Borland mesum itself? Abandonware is _not_ a legal concept and the code is still copyright by Borland/Inprise/Enchilada or whatever they call themselves this week. See http://edn.embarcadero.com/museum

Comment: @paxdiablo: you're right that abandonware is not legal. But if it's **correctly** declared as abandonware, then that means that you *can no longer buy the software from the owner*. So your only chance is to buy it used from someone who owns it (unless it's not really abandonware).

Comment: No, you can download it legally from Embarcadero, the current copyright owners (see the link I gave). And even if it wasn't obtainable from anywhere, that doesn't make it legal. The site given in the answer doesn't look like you're buying a legal used copy so much as downloading a file you have no right to - why do that when you can do it legally?

Comment: No problems, Pablo, but it'll _always_ be the Borland museum to we who care :-)

Answer (score 4):

> DJGPP is a complete 32-bit C/C++
>   development system for Intel 80386
>   (and higher) PCs running DOS. It
>   includes ports of many GNU development
>   utilities. The development tools
>   require a 80386 or newer computer to
>   run, as do the programs they produce.
>   In most cases, the programs it
>   produces can be sold commercially
>   without license or royalties.

http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/

Answer (score 3):

This will do it straight in the command line debugger in DOS.
http://www2.latech.edu/~acm/helloworld/dosdebug.html

It does write a COM file and not an EXE (there is a difference) but should be a good start for you.

Answer (score 2):

For C and C++ development, use one of these free and open source compilers:

- [DJGPP](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/) - a DOS port of GCC.  It builds 32-bit protected mode DOS applications.
- [Open Watcom](http://www.openwatcom.org/index.php/Main_Page) - I'm not as familiar with this one, but it's actively developed and can target 16- and 32-bit DOS, Windows, and OS/2.

Answer (score 0):

You want a MS-DOS C compiler. Is there still an old version of Borland C floating around? Also, you might find a port of the GNU C compiler for DOS.

Answer (score 0):

Install Turbo C/C++ 16-bit compiler. Then create new `noname00.c` file.
Write this code in it.

```
//Include necessary files stdio.h and conio.h for function prototypes.
//The "int agrc , char *argv[]" are optional parameters to main program.If you don't want to use //it you can just write "int main()"
int main(int argc,char *argv[])  
{  
     printf("Hello World !!!!");  
     getch();  
     return 0;  
}
```

the .exe file generated by this compiler can be found in source directory.
Try to run it in your own MS-DOS Box.
It should run.

Answer (score 0):

For Pascal you will want Free Pascal. It generates 32-bit Go32v2 binaries like DJGPP, and can compile old TP code.

Work is also being done on a Windows->16-bit Dos compiler (can generate .COM), but while working, that is not in a released branch yet.