# What does $ mean in MIPS assembly?

Tags: assembly, mips

What does `$` mean in MIPS Assembly language?

Take the example:

```
Add #$28,R4,R3
```

What is the dollar sign in the expression?

Comment: It'd be helpful if you mentioned **WHAT** kind of assembler this is. While it looks like MIPS, maybe this is actually some alien cpu being reverse engineered in Area 51. In which case, you'd better hope that the alien mothership hasn't installed Norton Antivirus yet.

Comment: If 1224 + $28 = 1264 then I'd assume that $ means hex because hex 28 = 40.

Comment: @RogerRowland Winner winner chicken dinner!

Comment: That's not standard MIPS assembly syntax.  Normal MIPS has the destination on the left, and register names decorated with `$`.  Like `addiu $3, $4, 0x28` if you're using register numbers instead of names like `$v0` and `$a0`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In some assemblers, the '$' means simply that you are using a hex value. on the x86 architecture it usual to write the number with 'h' or if the first character is not a digit, then you have to use a zero in front `28h` or `0afh`.
In C you would write `0x28`.

For example on the 6510 (Commodore 64) or M68000 (i.e. Amiga) the '$' character was used for this like '$28'. I'm sure there are other assemblers as well using this notation.

Comment: In x86 AT&T syntax (used by GNU `as`), `$` means an immediate constant, like `#` in some other assemblers (including ARM, and OP's code).  (In AT&T syntax, `.` means the address of the current instruction, like `$` in NASM, as mentioned by mcleod_ideafix's answer).  So in AT&T syntax, `add  esi, symbol` is a 4-byte load from an absolute address, while `add rsi, $symbol` uses the symbol's address as an imm32.  (Same for `add esi, 0x12345678` (absolute address) vs. `add esi, $0x12345678`)

Comment: Oops, my previous comment had the AT&T syntax wrong; destination operand goes last.  `add  symbol, %esi` is a 4-byte load from an absolute address, adding into ESI, while `add $symbol, %rsi` adds the symbol address as a sign_extended_imm32.

Answer (score 15):

In assemblers, symbol $ usually means two different things:

- Prefixing a number, means that this number is written in hexadecimal.
- By itself, $ is a numeric expression that evaluates as "the current position", that is, the address where the next instruction/data would be assembled.

For example:

```
mydata:     db 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,$a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f   ;some decimal and 
                                                      ;hexadecimal numbers
datalenght  equ $-mydata   ;length of previous list.

            jmp $          ;an infinite loop!! ($ evaluates as the current 
                           ;                     position just before the 
                           ;                     instruction is assembled, 
                           ;                     that is, the position where 
                           ;                     the JMP instruction begins)
```

You might also see $ at the end of string constants, as a string terminator character if you write or read programs written for CP/M or MS DOS. Both OS used this convention, so the system call to print a string to the console expects a dollar-terminated string. [Gary Kildall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gary_Kildall), the creator of [CP/M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP/M), never disclosed why he had chosen that particular symbol for marking the end of a string.

```
         ;A very simple MSDOS program to 
         ;display "Hello world" to console.
         org 100h   
         mov dx,offset Message
         mov ah,9
         int 21h
         int 20h
Message: db "Hello, world!",13,10,'$'
```

---

```
         ;A very simple CP/M program to 
         ;display "Hello world" to console.
         org $100
         mov de,Message
         mov c,9
         call 5  ;call bdos
         rst 0
Message: db "Hello, world!",13,10,'$'
```

Comment: Mentioning `$` as data (inside quotes) for MS-DOS string constants kind of distracts from the point about `$` as a syntactical element.  I had always wondered why such a non-obscure ASCII character was chosen as the MS-DOS string terminator ever since seeing it in 16-bit questions on SO, so thanks for the history lesson.

Comment: `Gary Kildall, the creator of CP/M, never disclosed why he had chosen that particular symbol ('$') for marking the end of a string.`  I assumed it was an obvious choice, with only a short list of symbols to choose from, *"Okay, which symbol will help us remember a keyword that starts with 'S'?  Ah yes, **the one that looks like an* `S` *:* `$` *!"***

Comment: It is better known as [Location Counter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41332233/2188550)