# Outputting Az-Za in MS-Debug

Tags: debugging, assembly, dos, x86-16

I'm currently struggling in outputting AzByCx in ms debug since I don't really know too much about it.
Included here are the [Basic commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIugk.png) that my teacher sent to us.

[image: Basic commands]

I can output A-Z easily, but not AzBxCy, there's not much of a detailed tutorial online so I came here to ask.

Comment: The 16-bit "accumulator" register is AX, not AC, unless DEBUG.EXE is an even worse assembler than I thought.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: `ax` is indeed the accumulator register. Debug uses `AC` in the flags dump to indicate Auxiliary Carry set, and `NA` instead to indicate it clear. Perhaps that's what got mixed up here.

Answer (score 2):

```
-e 200 "Az"
-a
1BD8:0100 mov bx, word [200]
1BD8:0104 mov cx, 3
1BD8:0107 mov ah, 2
1BD8:0109 mov dl, bl
1BD8:010B int 21
1BD8:010D mov dl, bh
1BD8:010F int 21
1BD8:0111 add bx, FF01
1BD8:0115 loop 109
1BD8:0117 mov dl, 0D
1BD8:0119 int 21
1BD8:011B mov dl, 0A
1BD8:011D int 21
1BD8:011F mov ax, 4C00
1BD8:0122 int 21
1BD8:0124
-g
AzByCx
```

What does this do?

- initialises word at `ds:200h` to the string "Az" (little endian low byte is "A", high byte is "z")
- use `A` command to assemble the following program:
- load from memory into register `bx` (to initialise the register without having to look up the numeric ASCII codepoints)
- set up `cx` as loop counter for three iterations
- set up register `ah` for the interrupt 21h service 02h (display character in `dl`)
- display character read from `bl` (low byte of `bx`)
- display character from `bh` (high byte of `bx`)
- add 1 to `bl` and -1 (in two's complement resulting in 0FFh) to `bh` which increments the codepoint in `bl` and decrements the one in `bh`
- loop back to display subsequent letters
- display a linebreak (codepoints 13 and 10, or 0Dh 0Ah) to make the output easier to read
- terminate program
- use `G` command to run the program

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft DEBUG.EXE can indeed be used to write a simple program in Intel-syntax assembly, see this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645032/msdos-hello-world-exe). Replace the string definition `db "Hello world$"` with `db "AzByCx$"` and you're done.

However, this is definitely not a good way how to learn assembly language.
Find a better teacher.